# How to remove deprecated iOS 14 widget

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

We have two widgets in our app, loaded in a `WidgetBundle`. We'd like to stop supporting one. Is there a way to remove it from the app and have it disappear from the user's homescreen and any stacks it may be in?

Comment: Can you just delete it from you code and send the update to the Appel Store? Only user that will update your application will have it removed.

Comment: @RolandLariotte It looks like that just breaks the widget on the home screen and doesn't actually remove it. Is the behavior different once it's been uploaded to the App Store?

Comment: It is hard to tell you how it would work out as you did not share any of your code. Please, provide minimal reproductible code that the community can test to solve your issue.

Comment: @RolandLariotte I actually have exactly the same question as @jamescs . The underlying problem is that if you delete a widget (or change it's identifier, f.ex.) - you end up with a blank, black rectangle on your homescreen, since the system has no longer this ID registered, etc.  So the question here -  is if there's any code lile `reloadAllTimelines` to clean up the screen from the obsolete widgets.